# Git: can't get branch commited after rebase

Tags: git, git-branch

I use Eclipse with EGit. I use a remote repository and I'm the only one working on it

I have a git repository that at some point looked something like this

```
A-B-C-D-E (Master)
     \
      C1-C2-C3 (branch: New_Design)
```

I then rebased my New_Design branch with Master to bring it into line with E

I understand this to mean it then should look like this

```
A-B-C-D-E (Master)
         \
          C1-C2-C3 (branch: New_Design)
```

When I subsequently added more changes to New_Design and committed all seemed to work.

```
A-B-C-D-E (Master)
         \
          C1-C2-C3-C4-C5-C6 (branch: New_Design)
```

But when I checked the remote repository, none of the commits were registered. The last commit that actually arrived was the post rebase commit.

When I go to the command line (EGit sometimes seems to swallow certain errors), I see this

```
To https://repo@bitbucket.org/project/project-web.git
! [rejected]        New_Design -> New_Design (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to    'https://repo@bitbucket.org/project/project-web.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

I tried that and executed

```
git pull -origin New_Design
```

as a result of this my project was overwritten with the old version from the repo. I saw all sorts of merge conflict with the default option Eclipse kept offering me was to accept the "old" version. Fortunately, I had made a local backup of the directory structure before this action and I basically overwrote it with the pre git pull disaster.

So, now I want to know what is the best way forward to get my stuff in the remote repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you rebase commits that have already been pushed to a remote repository, you need to specify the *force* flag when you push your newly rebased branch up to the remote.

```
git push origin New_Design -f
```

**Why this happens**

Your remote branch looks like:

```
A - B - C - C1 - C2 - C3
```

Following the rebase, your local branch looks like:

```
A - B - C - D - E - C1' - C2' - C3' - C4 - C5 - C6
```

To git, this looks like you've removed the commits `C1`, `C2`, and `C3`. In reality, the same (or very similar, unless you manually resolved conflicts) set of changes is contained in `C1'`, `C2'`, and `C3'`, so you won't lose work in this case. Since git can't know for sure, it makes you verify that you really want to do this by requiring the `-f` flag.

Force pushing can result in lost work on the remote branch in a variety of situations:

- If you have other people working on the remote repository and their changes aren't reflected in your local branch. Git is suggesting `git pull` to remedy this situation.
- If you've rewritten history on your local branch and removed or changed commits.

Since you're working alone, you're safe to do a force push if you're happy with your local branch.

Comment: An advice is to try to generally avoid `git-rebase` unless on your own local branches that are never pushed anywhere. For getting changes from another branch to your branch, which is possibly worked on by other people, use `git-merge` which has the equivalent effect (and is at times even much better).